# $f$ increasing , $c \in I$ ; $a_n<c<b_n , \forall n\in \mathbb N$ and $\lim \Big(f(a_n)-f(b_n) \Big)=0 $ , then $f$ is continuous at $c$ ?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Let $f:I \to \mathbb R$ be an increasing function where $I$ is an open real interval ; how to show that if for $c \in I$ there exist sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ such that $a_n<c<b_n , \forall n\in \mathbb N$ and $\lim \Big(f(a_n)-f(b_n) \Big)=0 $ , then $f$ is continuous at $c$ ? ( I can prove the converse but having trouble with this one ; Please Help )

Comment: Suppose $f$ is not continuous at $c$. Use the assumption that $f$ is increasing to conclude that $f$ has a jump discontinuity at $c$. Now use the assumption about the sequences.